# Issues with video playback running too fast on your Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: raspbian

Pls help. It is sooo urgent. I am experiencing issues with video playback running too fast on your Raspberry Pi Zero.

Comment: What video player are you using? Have you tried a different video player? Does the video player have replay speed control?

Comment: I should save video in avi or mp4 file

Comment: I use VNC video player.

Comment: Do you mean VLC not VNC? Do the same files play correctly on another machine using the same player?

Comment: are you completing an exam?

Comment: I guess that it's not all that urgent after all